# ASP.Net MVC Ajax, как реализовать удаление записи из бд

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"удалить", 
"DeleteComment", 
new { Id = element.Id }, 
new AjaxOptions { 
                HttpMethod = "Post", 
                Confirm = "Подтвердить удаление", 
                UpdateTargetId = "comments" }, 
new { id = element.Id, @class = "deleteComment" })
```

Запись удаляется, но страница не обновляется, как реализовать обновление страницы?

Comment: Укажите, какую базу данных вы используете и каким фреймворком пользуетесь для вазимодействия с ней.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, код View, а также код метода DeleteComment.

Answer (score 1):

У класса AjaxOptions есть свойство OnSuccess, которое принимает название js-функции, которая сработает при успешном выполнении операции. У него есть и другие свойства типа OnFailure и т.п.

Попробуйте написать свою функцию, которая будет выполнять необходимые вам действия после завершения запроса.

К примеру выглядеть это может вот так:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
"удалить", 
"DeleteComment", 
new { Id = element.Id }, 
new AjaxOptions {
                OnSuccess = "Foo",

                HttpMethod = "Post", 
                Confirm = "Подтвердить удаление", 
                UpdateTargetId = "comments" }, 
new { id = element.Id, @class = "deleteComment" })


<script>
    function Foo(){
        window.location.reload(); // Перезагрузка страницы
    }
</script>
```

Хотя, честно говоря, я не вижу смысла в перезагрузки страницы после аякс запроса, на мой взгляд, было бы красивее просто удалить/скрыть удаленный элемент со страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня более удобно использовать Jquery. Попробуйте на нем

js:

```
    function deleteUser(userId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/UserDetails/Delete',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Id: userId
        },
        success: function () {
            window.location="/"; //обнавление страницы
        }
    });
}
```

action:

```
// POST: UserDetails/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var userDetail = _userDetailsRepository.GetBy(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        _userDetailsRepository.Remove(userDetail);
        _userDetailsRepository.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```